# Is there anyway to rewrite class instance in memory by it's link?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, memory, instance-variables

For example... I have some class named `DisplayableUnit`.

Everywhere in the code a lot of different variables point to instances of that class, like:

```
List<DisplayableUnit> known_units;
DisplayableUnit CopiedUnit;
DisplayableUnit EditingUnit;
DisplayableUnit CurrentUnit;
```

and etc etc etc

Then, for example I need to replace some **instanceA** with newly created **instanceB**.
Is it possible to rewrite  class instance bytes of **instanceA**, so all other variables previously pointing onto **instanceA** would point to **instanceB** without changing own pointer?

I need that because I have SO MUCH variables pointing to instances, so it really hard to change those all.

My ideal way is something like:
`known_units[5] = instanceB; //and after that all other vars will lead onto instanceB`

Comment: Why don't you simply modify the instance itself ? e.g `known_units[5].Change(...)`

Comment: DisplayableUnit is very field rich class and have a lot of instances of other classes. Hard to modify that all.

Comment: I don't see any other solution not involving changes in all the code using the class instance. Plus, I don't see where's the difficulty in creating a constructor-like method in your class that re-set all the fields...

Comment: Looks like you are right, but I will hope for miracle a little longer.

Comment: Instead of changing all the variables, can you change internals of DisplayableUnit class? Turn it into a wrapper, which holds real object reference and redirects all calls. And when you need to change instance - modify instance inside the wrapper.

Comment: @Kosmos: I bet there's a dirty/hacky ways using unsafe code, but, as the name unsafe suggest, I would discourage taking that way...

Comment: @Alexander, I like that idea. Even through this is no answer, but a workaround, I still can accept it until real answer appear if it will ever appear.

Comment: @Alexander: to not break the compatibility with the code using DisplayableUnit objects, you need to expose the same properties/methods both in the wrapper that in the inner instance, and that's the same amount of work (if not more) than creating a method to change all the fields...

Comment: Based on Alexander's comment I decided to do it in own way, but with same idea. I created `Dictionary<int, DisplayableUnit> AllUnits;` and class `DULink` that stores guid and have DisplaybleUnit by guid getter. I still need to replace all vars with DUlink, but that's still works.

Comment: @Kosmos: that's a valid solution. I thought it was basically impossible for you to change all the places where DisplayableUnit was called, otherwise I (and for sure other people) would have suggested that ;)

Comment: there is around 300+ places where DisplayableUnit are used. this is really mess and i have to clean this junk. Thanks for answers :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose two possible solutions.

First is to modify the original object in an automatic way, e.g. with http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ and thus not having to deal with a lot of fields.

```
public void Change(DisplayableUnit other)
    {
        this.InjectFrom(other);
    }
```

The second is to a have all the variables point to a Wrapper of type DisplayableUnit and access the internal object trough a Value property.

```
public class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
```